# Difference between BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP and RoundingMode.HALF_UP?

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

The below:

```
new MathContext(precision, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

seems to work. However, the following returns an error:

```
new MathContext(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Error:

```
java: no suitable constructor found for MathContext(int,int)
    constructor java.math.MathContext.MathContext(java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor java.math.MathContext.MathContext(int,java.math.RoundingMode) is not applicable
      (actual argument int cannot be converted to java.math.RoundingMode by method invocation conversion)
    constructor java.math.MathContext.MathContext(int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: One is a `RoundingMode` and one is an `int` field of a `BigDecimal` - the error tells you that. Is there something more to your question?

Comment: Why is one `RoundingMode` and the other `int`? What is the difference between the two? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html doesn't really explain anything

Comment: Because `MathContext` is part of the java math API, as is `RoundingMode`. The `ROUND_HALF_UP` field of `BigDecimal` is part of `BigDecimal`'s own implementation detail.

Comment: So they're both just integers except one has type `RoundingMode` and the other has type `int`? Would it work if I cast `RoundingMode` to `int`? `RoundingMode` is just an enum of ints, right?

Comment: Why not look at the [code](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/math/RoundingMode-source.html)? Google is your friend. `RoundingMode` is an `enum`. And in fact one quick glance at the code tells you that `RoundingMode.valueOf(BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP) == RoundingMode.HALF_UP`. And in fact the comment in the code: _Returns the RoundingMode object corresponding to the **legacy** rounding modes_ (emphasis mine).

Comment: Enums are classes in Java. Not ints. Google for Java enum tutorial, and read it. If a variable has the type RoundingMode, then its type is RoundingMode, and not int.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the constants:

```
RoundingMode.HALF_UP
BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
```

mean absolutely the same according to Javadocs and according to source code:

```
public enum RoundingMode {
....
HALF_UP(BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP),
....
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use **BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP** instead of **RoundingMode.HALF_UP** because of RoundingMode.HALF_UP is calling BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP internally so both will give you same result but RoundingMode.HALF_UP will require one more step.

Sources from java doc:

**BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP**

*public static final RoundingMode HALF_UP
Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up. Behaves as for RoundingMode.UP if the discarded fraction is ≥ 0.5; otherwise, behaves as for RoundingMode.DOWN. Note that this is the rounding mode commonly taught at school. ([click here to know more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP))*

**RoundingMode.HALF_UP**

*public final static int ROUND_HALF_UP
Behave as for ROUND_UP if the discarded fraction is >= .5; otherwise, behave as for ROUND_DOWN. (Rounds towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case rounds up.) ([click here to know more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs45/classdocs/java.math.BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_UP))*